# open and close door, and restrict movement when closed

Tags: boolean, processing

I am trying to make a door that opens and closes randomly within 5-10 seconds.

This is what I have so far:

```
float doorRandom = random(5,10);
float doorRandomClose = random(5,10);

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
}

void draw() {
    if(millis()>doorRandom*1000){
     doorClosed();
   }
   else{
     doorOpen();
   }
}

void doorOpen() {
    noFill();
    rect(500,500,100,200);
}

void doorClosed() {
    fill(0);
    rect(500,500,100,200);
}
```

The door starts open, then after 5-10 seconds it will close. However, the door then remains closed. How do I get the door to open, close, open, close etc...

Also, I have a rectangle that is controlled with left and right arrow keys:

```
float x = 50;
float y = 500;
float speed = 50;

void display() {
      fill(255, 0, 0);                         
      rect(x, y, 40, 75);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(keyCode == LEFT && x > 50)
  {
    x = x - speed;
  }
  if(keyCode == RIGHT && x < 1000)
  {
    x = x + speed;
  }
}
```

My desire is to have it so when the door is open, the rectangle can pass through and go right to the right side of the screen, and when the door is closed, have the rectangle not be able to pass, so:

```
if(keyCode == RIGHT && x < 500)
```

How would I also achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the door to open and close by storing the openedness of the door in a boolean value, then generating a random time *inside the draw function* whenever you toggle the door between opened and closed.

You can then use this boolean value to allow the rectangle to pass through the door only when it is open by checking the x value of the rectangle and the openedness of the door, and limiting the movement of the rectangle when the door is not open so that it can not move through the door.

You will have to decide on a behaviour when the rectangle is inside the door when it closes.

An implementation to get you started:

```
float doorRandom = random(5,10);
bool doorOpened = false; // does Java have false?

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
}

void draw() {
    if(millis()>doorRandom*1000){
     doorOpened = !doorOpened; // Toggle door
     doorRandom = random(5,10);
    }
    if(doorOpened) {
     doorOpen();
   }
   else{
     doorClosed();
   }
}

void doorOpen() {
    noFill();
    rect(500,500,100,200);
}

void doorClosed() {
    fill(0);
    rect(500,500,100,200);
}
```

Comment: Something like this?
boolean dooropen = false
if (dooropen) { door open code }
if (!dooropen) { door closed code }

Then how would I implement a way to stop when the door is closed

Comment: I'd use `else`, but basically, yeah. You'd implement a way to stop by checking whether the rectangle was about to move into the space that the door occupies and, if so, remove its movement speed and move it so it's almost in the door but just next to it.

Comment: I have....
boolean doorOpen = false;

void setup() {
size(1000,1000);
}

void draw() {if (doorOpen) {
        noFill();
        rect(500,500,100,200);
      }
      if (!doorOpen) {
                fill(0);
        rect(500,500,100,200);
    }

How do I use the timer (5-10seconds) and also implement the stop when door closed?

Comment: @aadds Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, and you've probably  chosen the wrong technology to accomplish this task. However, you should add an if statement that checks whether the timer's up, and if it is you need to reset the timer. Then change the value of doorOpen so it represents whether the door is actually open.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to do that. I have been trying to do this for a while and I just cant get it. Could you maybe point me towards a guide or anything like that?

Comment: @aadds No, unfortunately; you're trying to make a game in Processing but, as you can probably tell from the name of the draw function, it's not really designed for that sort of thing. It can do it, since it's wrapped around Java, but people probably won't be writing guides about how to change and remember game states in Processing.

Comment: @aadds Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done any logic to re-open the door after it closes.

This line of code:

```
if(millis()>doorRandom*1000)
```

will always be true - and therefore the door will always remain close.

You need to reset the millis() function when you want to open the door again.

The best way to do that is something like this (its not pure javascript, but you get the idea):

```
time = currentTimeMillis() 


if(currentTimeMillis() - time >doorRandom*1000)...
```

and when you want to reset simply update the time again:

```
time = currentTimeMillis()
```